# Android Emulator device manager is not showing the icon for the test app

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, appium-android

Android Studio (Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2)  Emulator device manager is not showing the icon for the test app. When I start the app via Appium automated code, it works but selected test device does not show the app icon. Its true for any app.

I should see the app icon.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.